# Displaying Bundle products in my own custom design in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, bundled-product

How to display a bundle product in my design. Just need to display using the core function. Bundled product is more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This solution has been provided considering you don't want to apply existing design and want a custom design for your product's page.

Create a new theme by copy and pasting your current working theme. Keep **template** and **layout** files which are related to product view page and **delete rest of files** from **`app/design/<package>/<theme>`** folder.

Apply that theme for your bundled products by:

- Login to admin panel and go to **Catalog -> Manage Products**.
- Click on product row for which you want to change theme.
- Click on Design tab under product edit page.
- Select the theme which you just created from **Custom Design** field under **Design** tab. Choose appropriate page layout from **Page Layout** field if necessary.
- Save product.

Now you can make changes in theme files which you selected to have different layout as per your requirement.